# Solve systems of linear equations in Excel without using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Suppose you have the following system of linear equations and want to solve for *x*, *y*, and *z*:

- 2x + y - z = -1
- -4x + 11y = 18
- x - y + 2z = 9

Is there an easy way to do this with Excel using worksheet functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by using a little linear algebra and Excel's matrix functions.

First, create an augmented matrix that represents your equations on a worksheet.

Since you want to solve for three variables, select 3 cells in a column where you want your results to be returned.  Without changing the selection, type the following formula:

```
=MMULT(MINVERSE(A2:C4),D2:D4)
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula in the selected array.  And that will return the solution to your system of equations.

[image]

This will work for larger systems of equations with more variables as well. This formula works based on the observation that the left-hand side of a system of linear equations can be represented as the product of an *n* by *n* matrix, ***A***, and an *n* by 1 matrix of variables, ***x***, and the right-hand side can be represented as an *n* by 1 matrix, ***B***. To solve this matrix equation, both sides must be multiplied by the inverse of ***A***.

> ***Ax*** = ***B***
>   inverse(***A***)***Ax*** = inverse(***A***)***B***
>   ***x*** = inverse(***A***)***B***

Thus, the solutions are just the matrix product of the inverse of the square matrix and the matrix of the constants on the right-hand side of the equations.